# friedmanmc() already account for the accumulation of Type I error?

Tags: r, bonferroni

Does the friedmanmc() function for post-hoc tests in R already account for the accumulation of Type I errors, or is it necessary to apply a Bonferroni correction to the returned p-values? I'm referring to the 'pgirmess' library.